# Open Parse Notification in a new Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, parse-platform

am working on an android project that has 3 tabs(fragments) running inside the main activity. I want to open the notification sent from parse,in the notification tab instead of opening the main activity. Have read all the answers related to this here but did not work. Here is my code below.
Here is the code that receives the Notification

```
 Intent launchActivity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    launchActivity.setAction("op_notify");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchActivity, 0);
    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_push)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(0, noti);
```

And the code in the MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action!=null)
    {
        Log.e("Received action",action);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Shownotifications shownotifications = new Shownotifications();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.pager, shownotifications);

    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    tabLayout= (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(manager));

    tabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    tabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });
    tabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i)
    {
        Fragment frag=null;
        if(i==0)
        {
            frag = new PostsView();

        }
        if(i==1)
        {
            frag= new Favourite();

        }
        if(i==2)
        {

            frag= new Shownotifications();
        }


        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 3;
    }
     @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if(position==0){
            return "Posts";
        }

        if(position==1){
             return "Favourite";
         }

         if(position==2){
             return "Notifications";
         }

        return "Default";
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `Parse Push Notification` or the system `Notification`? The Notification in your question is for example or is it how it really does?

Comment: The notification is when i push from parse, then you draw your toolbar for it to appear. On click i want to open a fragment.